# Error: Python packaging tool 'pip' not found

Tags: package-management

Whatever packages I try to install in pycharm I keep getting an error saying:

```
Error: Python packaging tool 'pip' not found
```

My python version is 3.4.2 in Ubuntu 14.10. Please help.

Comment: and you actually installed "pip"? By the way: please install  a supported release if you want help from Ask Ubuntu. 14.10 went end of life a long time ago.

Comment: Specifically, what does `sudo apt-get install python-pip` do?

Answer (score 2):

Please check if you have pip installed.

```
which pip
```

might already help - or check dpkg via

```
dpkg -l | grep pip
```

Both methods should tell you if you have pip installed or not.

If it isn't installed so far, install it via:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

Comment: edwardo@edwardo-HP-ProBook-6450b:~$ dpkg -l | grep pip
ii  libpipeline1:i386                                   1.3.1-1                                  i386         pipeline manipulation library
----------------------------------i got that output----------

Comment: That means the only package you got installed & dpkg knows of  containing the string 'pip' is 'libpipeline1:i386 1.3.1-1 i386'. If your system would have an installed package python-pip it should be listed in the output. Therefor the fix should be installing it as mentioned in my base-post via apt.

Answer (score 2):

If you have python3, use the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Comment: thanks man. i had a problem with it for a week. now i am free.

Answer (score 1):

This problem comes because we might be unknowingly using some packages from python3 and for this we would need pip for python3

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

this would work.